Windows 10: how to prevent the mouse wheel from scrolling horizontally
In Windows 10 (but generically in any Windows version AFAIK),
turning the mouse wheel inside any window (WheelUp / WheelDown) may trigger horizontal scroll.
(e.g., Windows Explorer folder with a horizontal scrollbar but not a vertical one, usually seen in List view)
I find this behavior very annoying and counter-intuitive, so I am trying to disable it without success.
Setting WheelScrollChars to 0 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop unfortunately has no effect.
Is there any way to prevent horizontal scrolling in such cases?

Look at mouse settings.  Some mice have the option to reassign the functions of buttons and wheel.  Whats your mouse brand?

@RohitGupta sorry but this has nothing to do with the problem I described. It is really Windows that whenever the mouse pointer is located on a window or element which can be just scrolled horizontally (as an Explorer window with just a horizontal scrollbar) it maps the mouse wheel to horizontal scrolling. I was simply wondering if some hidden registry key exists to prevent this. The mouse model and driver is irrelevant, Windows has the same behavior with any mice

Yes, scrolling over a horizontal scroll bar moves the window horizontally. That's normal behavior. It's not that it MAY scroll horizontally, it WILL scroll horizontally when over a horizontal movement control like the scroll bar, so long as that control is active and the windows has horizontal space to scroll to. Horizontal scroll bars typically occupy a very small part of a UI: is this truly a problem?

@music2myear dunno, sometimes people seem commenting just to gain scores... my question was not whether the behavior is normal or not, I know it is normal but ANNOYING, so I wondered whether any way or registry tweak existed to prevent it.

You don't earn reputation from up votes on your comments, so no, I'm not "commenting just to gain scores". Current Windows versions rely less on the registry for UI and core functions than it has in the past. You could try to intercept these inputs using a utility such as AHK. I'm not sure there's going to be an easy way to do this though, and it certainly won't be universal, because the horizontal scrolls on modern UI elements likely have different hooks than those of legacy apps.
